# Try add field "location" in invoice pdf on PrestaShop 1.7.x

Tags: prestashop-1.7

in my prestashop 1.7.x i want show the field "location" (from table product) in the pdf invoice.

The .tpl file that manage the pdf invoice is:
/pdf/invoice.product-tab.tpl

I note that in this tpl file the variable  {$product['location']} is not view.

Then, in the above tpl file, i try to get the field location value (for each product in the order), by the follow code:

```
    <!-- PRODUCTS -->
    {foreach $order_details as $order_detail}
        {cycle values=["color_line_even", "color_line_odd"] assign=bgcolor_class}
    
            {* INSERT THE CODE *}
            {* Language id *}
            {$lang_id = (int) Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')}
            {* Product id *}
            {$id_product = $order_detail.product_id}
            {* Load product object *}
            { $product = new Product($id_product, false, $lang_id) }
```

and after try to print the value by:

```
{$product->location}
```

but the value is not show, and the code

"{ $product = new Product($id_product, false, $lang_id) } "
and
"{$product->location}"

are printed in invoice.

Where am I wrong?
Thank you